# UI altering only works in viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios

I'm manually changing the height of the `UINavigationBar` in my custom `UINavigationController` subclass. For some reason when I add the code to alter the height in the `viewDidAppear` function the bar's height is correctly changed, but when I try putting the code in the `viewDidLoad` nothing happens. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
class PetNavigationVC: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
        self.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 74)

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: In viewDidLoad() the nslayout constraints and so on have not yet been calculated. The uiview components have been loaded into memory, instantiated from your xib or storyboard, but they have not yet been laid out.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, in viewDidLoad method the constraints aren't even calculated and nothing is really loaded except for your class values. Also adding code to viewDidLoad can be a bit tricky too, because user can see what's happening right on demant :D

You should adjust your frames or any UI related stuff in viewWillAppear func or in method DidLayoutSubviews...